# Including timestamp in a file name

Tags: shell, timestamp

I have a set of files and I need to merge them into one. The merged file should be in the following format in shell script:

```
cdr-cdr-<currentTimeStamp>.csv 
e.g cdr-cdr-20150630125400.csv
```

Currently I am doing:

```
cat *.csv >> merge.txt
```

Here I need to rename the merge.txt file as above mentioned format.

How to incorporate timestamp in the file name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `date`:

```
cat *.csv >> cdr-cdr-$(date +%s).csv
```

The `%s` format is the timestamp, see `date`'s manpage:

```
   %s     seconds since 1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC
```